# Ruby error expecting keyword end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to show images using will_paginate. I am getting and expecting keyword_end issue.

Here is the .erb that is throwing the error. The error is at the line with image_tag

```
<h2>My Links</h2><br>
  <p>Check out the links you've shared here, or <a href="/add-link">add a new link</a></p>

<p>
  <strong>My Links</strong><br />
  <ul class="">
    <% @links.each do |link| -%>
      <li> <a href="<%= link.content %>"><%= link.title %></a><br /> </li>

      <li> <%= link.description %><br /> </li>
      <li> <%= link.category %><br /> </li>
      <% if link.image_blob %>
      <%= image_tag url_for(:action => 'show_image', :id => link.id), :size => "300x200") %>
      <% end %>

    <% end -%>
  </ul>
</p>

<%= will_paginate @links, :page_links => false %>
```

and here is my application helper function

```
 def show_image
    puts "in show_image"
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    send_data @link.image_blob, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
  end
```

Comment: Unrelated, but consider not using break tags for spacing.

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: Dodging the problem a little, but does this work?
`image_tag url_for(:action => 'show_image', :id => link.id, :size => "300x200") if link.image_blob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two closing parentheses on the image line.

Comment: I think I can only choose one as the answer. I'll choose this one because it was first. I have to wait a few minutes before it let's me do this.
Thanks! What a silly typo.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line will be the problem

```
image_tag url_for(:action => 'show_image', :id => link.id), :size => "300x200")
```

It has closing bracket ")" after link.id and at the end

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched parentheses on the line with image_tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:action => 'show_image', :id => link.id), :size => "300x200") %>
```

You have an extra ")" at the end of this line. I believe this is your problem.